# How can you change the view from within an angular fullCalendar template?

Tags: javascript, angular, view, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

It currently displays the whole month but I would like it to display only 10 days at the time.

This is my current code

```
<full-calendar #calendar [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [events]="events" [weekends]="false" [contentHeight]="400" [fixedWeekCount]="false" [displayEventEnd]="true"}">
 </full-calendar>
```

And I would like to add this, but on my template

```
   defaultView: "tenDays",
        views: {
          tenDays: {
            type: 'dayGrid',
            duration: { days: 10 }
          }
        }
```

I tried to do it on the ts. file like this but it didn't apply the changes on the template

```
@ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;

    ngOnInit() {
          .......
          this.calendarComponent.dayCount = 10;
         ......
      }
```

Comment: I suggest you declare the views as an object, and then reference that object in your template.

Comment: I tried to, but it doesn't apply it for some reason

Comment: Please show exactly what you tried. Does it generate any console errors? I'm not an Angular expert but I'm sure someone will be able to point you in the right direction, if you show your attempt. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61485042/edit) to update us.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However I can't see how those changes bear any relation to setting either the `defaultView` or `views` options on your template. And I've no idea what the `#calendar` bit is supposed to represent. I'd have been expecting something like `[defaultView]="tenDays" and `[views]="views"` where `views` is the name of an object somewhere else in the code (just like `calendarPlugins` is in the `[plugins]="calendarPlugins"` option, and just like `events` is in the `[events]="events"` option.)

Comment: (and the dayCount will have no impact at all if you aren't using a custom view at the time. Your attempt to change the code looks like it is mostly guesswork, rather than noticing what goes on in the existing code, and/or reading the documentation in detail.)

Comment: I forgot to add the @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; part. This is where the 'calendar' comes from

Comment: yes but as far as I know it's not necessary to write `#calendar` inside the `<full-calendar` tag. That's what I meant. It's not shown in any documentation / examples.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular If you look at the "Accessing FullCalendar’s API" you fill find where the #calendar inside the tag comes from

Comment: Ah ok thankyou, I didn't see that. Anyway, have you tried adding those view-related properties as I suggested?